# Error in using setTimeout to extract the result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

There is a error for my script for using the setTimeout function

For example, my script is sth like

```
function student() {
    var obj = {
      name: "Mary", 
    number: +44 26281001
    }
 return obj  
}
```

And I would like to delay the execution of the function for 4 second later and then save to the variable x. 
I wrote the following function:

```
var x = setTimeout(student(), 4000);
```

And it returns a number 1280, and 4 second later it returns errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

What is the error and how should I fix it?
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function as the argument. You are giving it the result of a call to `student`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your number should be enclosed like

```
number: '+44 26281001'
// or
number: "+44 26281001"
```

so that `number` becomes a string. And pass the function itself as parameter instead of calling it and passing the result of `student()` as the parameter.

```
var x = setTimeout(student, 4000);
```

Btw, if you want to assign/log the student object, then you need to call it like this:

```
setTimeout(()=>console.log(student()), 4000);
```

EDIT

```js
function student() {
  return {
    name: 'Mary',
    number: '+44 26281001'
  }
}

var studentVar;

var x = setTimeout(function() {
  studentVar = student();
}, 4000);
console.log(x);
console.log(studentVar); // Logs 'undefined'

(function logXAfter5Seconds() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(studentVar); // Logs the student object after 5 seconds
  }, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! I run the code as you said again, however, when I tried to use the console.log(x) after 4 second, I thought that  it shows me another number 2586 and undefined again..  why?

Comment: See the edit, it displays the timer Id returned by setTimeout() call immediately and after.

Comment: And still one more question, if I want to assign/log the student object, is there alternative way besides ES6?

Comment: Updated the answer to demonstrate how to assign the result of student() function.

Comment: Thanks again! Really, the last question, for those number that return before e.g 1280, what is that means?

Comment: From MDN: "The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout."